# No ECS agent docker container in ECS optimised instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I launched an ECS Optimised instance in ap-south-1 region of AWS from ami id: ami-0a8bf4e187339e2c1 using the link https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-optimized_AMI.html but there is no ecs agent present. Even `/var/log/ecs` directory is not present so I cannot check logs. I have correct cluster name configured in `/etc/ecs/ecs.config`

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the instances in the EC2 console in AWS, can you see the AMI ID? Is it the AMI ID you expect?

Just to have a point of comparison, I just SSH'd to an ECS-optimized EC2 instances and I can see `ecs-agent` in a `docker ps` listing, I can see `/var/log/ecs`, so my first instinct is that this EC2 instance didn't end up using the AMI you expected it to.

Comment: Yes, AWS fixed the AMI after I raised this issue with them. However, it is still not able to throw logs in Cloudwatch and task definition fails to launch if I put log driver as awslogs.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check logs go to tasks and click on the task in which you wan to see logs and then click on logs yo will see the logs of your container.